Infer `pyarrow.DataType` from Python type?
Consider the following example:
from typing import Any, get_type_hints
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pac

ArrowTypes = {
    int: pa.int64(),
    str: pa.string(),
}

class StructLike:
    __attr_types__: dict[str, Any] = {}
    __attr_annotations__: dict[str, Any]

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__["__attr_annotations__"] = get_type_hints(self)

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        try:
            val_type = type(value)
            if issubclass(self.__attr_annotations__[name], val_type):
                self.__attr_types__[name] = type(value)
                self.__dict__[name] = value
            else:
                raise TypeError(
                    f"'{name}' should have type "
                    f"{self.__attr_annotations__[name]}, "
                    f"but instead it has type {val_type}"
                )
        except TypeError as e:
            raise e
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError(
                f"Could not find '{name}' in {self.__attr_annotations__=}"
            )

    def as_dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {k: getattr(self, k) for k in self.__attr_annotations__.keys()}
    def arrow_type(self) -> pa.StructType:
        return pa.struct(
            [
                pa.field(name, ArrowTypes[ty])
                for name, ty in self.__attr_types__.items()
            ]
        )

    def to_arrow(self) -> pa.StructScalar:
        return pac.cast(
            self.as_dict(),
            target_type=self.arrow_type(),
        )


class PyStruct(StructLike):
    aleph: str
    bet: int

    def __init__(self, aleph: str, bet: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.aleph = aleph
        self.bet = bet


test = PyStruct("hello", 5)
test.to_arrow()

It works:
<pyarrow.StructScalar: [('aleph', 'hello'), ('bet', 5)]>

But I have to rely on the hand-built ArrowTypes dictionary to map from Python types to a pa.DataType in the method StructLike.arrow_type. How can I infer a simple pa.DataType from a given (simple) Python type in an automatic fashion?

You can do it yourself by looking at the class metadata. I do it with dataclasses. I don't think you'll find an automated way of doing it out of the box. It's an opinionated process. For instance, what data type would you use for int? int32 int64? Or datetime.datetime? Which resolution and timezone to use.

@0x26res Fair enough. I just thought there must be some automated way to do it for simple enough types. For other types, "sane defaults". Not sure.
